# how to figure out why there are two group in my plot

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have an Integer vector with approx. 18000 observations.
At first it was a list, but when trying to use some plot function I got some errors, so I changed it into a integer vector as so:

Input:

```
data <- read.csv("gumdrops.csv")
head(data)
```

Output:

```
X01 X02 X03 X04 X05 X06 
  0   0   1   0   0   2
```

Input:

```
str(data_new)
```

Output:

```
Named int [1:18828] 0 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:18828] "X01" "X02" "X03" "X04" ...
```

Input:

```
summary(data)
data_new <- unlist(data)
plot(data_new)
```

output for the last line of code above:

[image: output for the last line of code above]

data_new sample set [0:20] :

```
0
0
1
0
0
2
3
0
0
0
0
3
3
1
6
5
6
1
6
6
```

I am new to Data Analysis, and I see there are so two different clusters in the graph. But I do not know what to make of it or why there are two clusters.

Any ideas? Or any advice as to how to understand the graph better?

Comment: Please share `head(data_new)` and `str(data_new)`.

Comment: Ok, have added it to my post :) @MKR

Comment: The graph is correct. `x-axis` shows index number of data in vector `data_new` and `y-axis` shows value at each point/index. try `plot(sample(1:10,20, replace = T))` and you will understand what happening

Comment: I ran the code of `plot(sample(data_new,20, replace = T))`, but I do not understand what I am looking at :/ Or why `sample()` is used, could you explain a little bit more  @MKR

Comment: Run exactly `plot(sample(1:10,20, replace = T))` code. It will help you understand how plot works. Also have a look at output of `sample(1:10,20, replace = T)`

Comment: Hello, @MKR :) I still did not understand the meaning behind your suggestion. I looked up what `sample()` is supposed to do...but it just made me more confused :(

Comment: No problem. Let me explain it. You have around 188K+ data points. It is clearly evident from graph that data points are frequently varying between `2` ranges and values are gradually increasing. Since number points are very large it looks overlapping otherwise points has been discretely drawn.  That explains the graph. Now one can say that points suggested that distribution of 2 formulas has been merged in 1 vector to have this kind of impression/graph.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share part of `csv` files? May be you have merged two different series in one vector.  Or drawing just first `2500` points will provide some additional info.

Comment: @MKR I can share part of csv file, how would I share it on here?

Comment: You can share it part of question itself. May be just add 10-20 lines from it.

Comment: @MKR have added it :)

Answer (score 0):

You flattened your data. Why?

What you are seeing is probably because X01 X02 X03 X04 X05 X06 do not have the same distribution. Which is unsurprising, as you usually cannot assume different attributes to have the same distribution.

I assume you either want to plot only single variables, or, e.g., a scatter plot of X01 vs. X02.

Comment: So, I just wanted to make my data a vector so that I could plot it. I used `data_new <- unlist(data)` so that I could plot. Should it be `data_new <- c(data)` instead? I just want to plot the data points how they are, if that makes sense....to read in my csv file I did `data <- read.csv("gumdrops.csv")` . Which is ~18800 x 1

Comment: Well, I cannot tell what would be the correct solution, as I don't know what the data is for. Just hacking random code never was a good idea. Step back from the keyboard, and rethink what you *should* do, not what you know how to code.